# Converting CFG to CNF,is it correct?

Tags: chomsky-normal-form

Given this CFG

```
 S->A|t|pCq
 S->B|r|^
 A->C|q|BA
 C->S|p|^
 B->m
```

My try to convert in CNF

Removing Null productions first i.e S->^ and C->^

So after removing

```
S->A|t|pCq
S->B|r
A->C|q|BA
C->S|p
B->m
```

Now removing unit productions i.e S->B, A->C, S->A and C->S

```
 S->B gives S->m using B->m

 A->C gives A->p using C->p

 S->A gives S->q|BA using  A->q|BA 

 C->S gives C->t|pCq|r using S->t|pCq
```

so adding these productions

```
S->t|pCq|q|BA

S->r|m

A->q|BA|p

C->p|t|pCq|r
```

where K->q,U->p

required CNG in CNF is

```
S->t|UCK|q|BA

S->r|m

A->K|BA|U

C->U|t|UCK|r
```

R->UC

```
S->t|RK|q|BA

S->r|m

A->K|BA|U

C->U|t|RK|r

R->UC 

K->q

U->p
```

Is this one correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Removing the Null productions. Some definitions allow S to have a null production, you removed the C production incorrectly. You were supposed to create another production for each production which had a C in the RHS by replacing the C with null.

   ```
   S->A|t|pCq|pq
   S->B|r
   A->^|q|BA
   C->S|p
   B->m
   ```

   *Note: After processing C->^, when you move to S->^, you do not add another C->^ production since that has already been processed. A->^ must be added however (A->C & C->^).*
2. Remove the A -> ^ production

   ```
   S->A|t|pCq|pq
   S->B|r
   A->B|q|BA
   C->S|p
   B->m
   ```
3. Remove A->B and S->B

   ```
   A->m|q|BA
   S->A|m|t|r|pCq|pq
   ```
4. Remove C->S

   ```
   C->A|p|m|t|r|pCq|pq
   ```

   *Notice how A is also added since S->A hasn't been processed (easier to process it first, I'm just demonstrating a point)*
5. Remove C->A

   ```
   C->q|p|m|t|r|pCq|pq|BA
   ```
6. Remove S->A

   ```
   S->q|m|t|r|pCq|pq|BA
   ```
7. Final
       S->m|r|q|t|pCq|pq|BA
       A->m|q|BA
       C->m|p|q|t|r|pCq|pq|BA
       B->m
8. Convert to CNF

   ```
   P->p
   Q->q
   X->CQ
   S->m|r|q|t|PX|PQ|BA
   A->m|q|BA
   C->m|p|q|t|r|PX|PQ|BA
   B->m
   ```

*Optional:*

```
S->^
```

EDIT: Oops. I made a mistake. Forgot to add C->r. Sorry ^^'

Comment: How did you remove the unit productions? I mean, while adding new productions e.g when C->S then which productions of S we will add to C i.e productions of S after removing unit production which are (S -> m|r|q|t|pCq|pq|BA) or  from given CFG     (S->A|t|pCq|pq) except A ?

Comment: And why you didn't remove C->S where S->^ while removing null productions?

Comment: When you remove C->S, for every production of the form S->U (U can be anything, terminals, variables, their combination), you add another production, C->U UNLESS U is a variable and S->U has already been removed @Kashiii
I'll update my answer

Comment: @Kashiii I edited the answer, and corrected a mistake. I still don't understand the second comment.
If you have to remove S->^, you are supposed to add new productions to make for that one removed production.